# Phpbb Spam Delete

Tags: forum, phpbb

I installed phpbb forum in my website. But there is lot of spam topics and spam post in it right now.

I went through many googling and found out that if I install a captcha module then I could prevent spam. But is there anyway I could remove spam which is already in the forum database now? I mean without using delete for each post/topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In phpbb admin, goto admin tab "**USERS AND GROUPS**", then under "**User security**" click **prune users**. Under the prune users text box is a select member link which will popup a member list. Under the member name(spammer) click select. So you can select all the spammers you want. Under the member select link are some radio buttons.

> Delete pruned user posts: 
>   Removes posts made by deleted users, has no
>   effect if users are deactivated.

Click: Yes

> Deactivate or delete: 
>   Choose whether to deactivate users or delete
>   them entirely. Please note that deleted users cannot be restored!

Click: Delete

Comment: Does "Delete" user also delete post?  (For spammers, this is desirable)  Also, phpBB 3 (3.0.13 for me) the *select member* link is called *Find A Member*, and it's about mid-page, under the multi-user-name box.

Comment: And if you were fool enough to forget to check that box when you pruned?